# Enabling labs features using GData API

Tags: c#, .net, google-email-settings-api

I am build an application(with .Net) in order to automatically configure our own domain gmail.

I can setting many thing using the API as described here : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#api_operations

But, Is it possible to enable features in Labs using the API (Labs Tab on Gmail setting)? I can't find any alternative to do this !

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet. Google has recently launched inside Google Apps Dashboard to advanced Labs management however there isn't any API available yet.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I decide to use Selenium WebDriver to achieve my goal !